# Kubernetes pod cannot access service which is running on another node

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, flannel

I'm trying to setup a k8s cluster. I've already deployed an ingress controller and a cert manager. However, currently I'm trying to deploy a first small service (Spring Cloud Config Server) and noticed that my pods cannot access services that are running on other nodes.

The pod tries to resolve a dns name which is publicly available and fails in this attempt due to a timeout while reaching the coredns-service.

My Cluster looks like this:

Nodes:

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION              CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8s-master   Ready    master   6d17h   v1.17.2   10.0.0.10     <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64   docker://19.3.5
node-1       Ready    <none>   6d17h   v1.17.2   10.0.0.11     <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64   docker://19.3.5
node-2       Ready    <none>   6d17h   v1.17.2   10.0.0.12     <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   5.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64   docker://19.3.5
```

Pods:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cert-manager    cert-manager-c6cb4cbdf-kcdhx              1/1     Running            1          23h     10.244.2.22   node-2       <none>           <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-cainjector-76f7596c4-5f2h8   1/1     Running            3          23h     10.244.1.21   node-1       <none>           <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-webhook-8575f88c85-b7vcx     1/1     Running            1          23h     10.244.2.23   node-2       <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-5kghx                       1/1     Running            1          6d16h   10.244.1.23   node-1       <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-kvh5b                       1/1     Running            1          6d16h   10.244.0.6    k8s-master   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-rrq4r                       1/1     Running            1          6d16h   10.244.2.21   node-2       <none>           <none>
project1        config-server-7897679d5d-q2hmr            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          103m    10.244.1.22   node-1       <none>           <none>
project1        config-server-7897679d5d-vvn6s            1/1     Running            1          21h     10.244.2.24   node-2       <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-6955765f44-7ttww                  1/1     Running            2          6d17h   10.244.2.20   node-2       <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-6955765f44-b57kq                  1/1     Running            2          6d17h   10.244.2.19   node-2       <none>           <none>
kube-system     etcd-k8s-master                           1/1     Running            5          6d17h   10.0.0.10     k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-apiserver-k8s-master                 1/1     Running            5          6d17h   10.0.0.10     k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-controller-manager-k8s-master        1/1     Running            8          6d17h   10.0.0.10     k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-flannel-ds-amd64-f2lw8               1/1     Running            11         6d17h   10.0.0.10     k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-flannel-ds-amd64-kt6ts               1/1     Running            11         6d17h   10.0.0.11     node-1       <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-flannel-ds-amd64-pb8r9               1/1     Running            12         6d17h   10.0.0.12     node-2       <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-b64jt                          1/1     Running            5          6d17h   10.0.0.12     node-2       <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-bltzm                          1/1     Running            5          6d17h   10.0.0.10     k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-fl9xb                          1/1     Running            5          6d17h   10.0.0.11     node-1       <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-scheduler-k8s-master                 1/1     Running            7          6d17h   10.0.0.10     k8s-master   <none>           <none>
```

Services:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE     SELECTOR
cert-manager    cert-manager                         ClusterIP   10.102.188.88    <none>        9402/TCP                     23h     app.kubernetes.io/instance=cert-manager,app.kubernetes.io/name=cert-manager
cert-manager    cert-manager-webhook                 ClusterIP   10.96.98.94      <none>        443/TCP                      23h     app.kubernetes.io/instance=cert-manager,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=webhook,app=webhook
default         kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      6d17h   <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx                        NodePort    10.101.135.13    <none>        80:31080/TCP,443:31443/TCP   6d16h   app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
project1        config-server                        ClusterIP   10.99.94.55      <none>        80/TCP                       24h     app=config-server,release=config-server
kube-system     kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       6d17h   k8s-app=kube-dns
```

I've noticed that my newly deployed service has no access to the coredns service on node-1. My coredns service has two pods of which no one is running on node-1. If I understand it correctly it should be possible to access the coredns pods via the service ip (10.96.0.10) on every node whether or not it runs on it.

I've already noticed that the routing tables on the nodes look like this:

```
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 proto static 
10.0.0.1 dev eth1 scope link 
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.1.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.1.1 
10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

So as you see there is no route to the 10.96.0.0/16 network.

I've already checked the ports and the `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` and `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables` sysctl values. All flannel ports are reachable and should be able to receive traffic over the 10.0.0.0/24 network.

Here is the output of `iptables -L` on the node-1:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target                  prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-SERVICES           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL           all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT                  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT                  icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT                  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT                  tcp  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere            
ACCEPT                  udp  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere            
ACCEPT                  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG                     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 15/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "Dropped by firewall: "
DROP                    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target                    prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-FORWARD              all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES             all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
DOCKER-USER               all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER                    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT                    all  --  10.244.0.0/16        anywhere            
ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere             10.244.0.0/16       

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target         prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT         udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target                    prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN                    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
ACCEPT     all  --  10.244.0.0/16        anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.244.0.0/16        /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.99.94.55          /* project1/config-server:http has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:http reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The cluster is deployed via ansible.

I'm sure I'm doing anything wrong. However I couldn't see it. 
Can somebody help me here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access the core dns IP from the host machine or form another pod?

Comment: From another pod. This is the problem with the one config-server pod which is stucking in CrashLoopBackOff.

Comment: So you are unable to access another pod form config-server pod and that's why config server pod is crashing ? But why do you refer codedns in your question?

Comment: The problem is that the config-server pod tries to resolve a DNS name which it can't do because it cannot reach the coredns at 10.96.0.10:53.

Comment: Where is the cluster deployed and what tool used to deploy it?

Comment: I've deployed it on cloud-vms at hetzner and deployed them using ansible.

Comment: Where you using any specific guide for Ansible provisioning or is it just your configuration. Is there any chance you used Kubespray?

Comment: I've used the universe package from geerlingguy (geerlingguy.kubernetes).
Thank you for your hint on kubespray. I would have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue on Kubernetes with the Calico network stack under Debian Buster.

Checking a lot of configs and parameters, I ended up with getting it to work by changing the policy for the forward rule to `ACCEPT`. This made it clear that the issue is somewhere around the firewall. Due to security considerations I changed it back.

Running `iptables -L` gave me the following unveiling warning: `# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them`

The output given by the list command does not contain any Calico rules. Running `iptables-legacy -L` showed me the Calico rules, so it seems obvious now why it didn't work. So Calico seems to use the legacy interface.

The issue is the change in Debian to `iptables-nft` in the alternatives, you can check via:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives | grep iptables
```

Doing the following:

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy
```

Now it works all fine!
Thanks to *Long* at the Kubernetes Slack channel for pointing the route to solving it.

Comment: Hi @calloc_org, I encountered the similar issue but did not see the warnings as you. Could you please invite me to the k8s slack channel maybe I can get some direct help there.

Comment: Just register for it here: https://slack.k8s.io/

Comment: Thanks, but after  input my email address then pass the reCAPTCHA I never received any emails even see "WOOT. CHECK YOUR EMAIL!" message. I have tried two addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the suggestion from Dawid Kruk and tried it with kubespray. Now it works as intended. If I'm able to figure out were my mistake was, I would post it here for the future.

Edit: Solution

My firewall rules were too restrictive. Flannel creates a new interfaces and since my rules are not restricted to my main interface nearly every package from flannel was dropped. If I had viewed the journalctl more attentive, I've found the issue earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the exact issue here. But I would like to clarify few things to make things more clear.

Cluster IPs are virtual IPs. They are not routed via routing tables. Instead, for each cluster IP, kube-proxy adds NAT table entries on its respective node. To check those entries, execute command `sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v`.

Now, core dns pods are exposed via a service cluster IP. Hence, whenever a packet comes to a node having destination address as cluster IP, its destination address is changed to the pod IP address which is routable from all the nodes (thanks to flannel). This change in destination address is done via a DNAT target entry in the iptables which looks like below.

```
Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination   
KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4  tcp  --  anywhere             10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP */ tcp dpt:domain

Chain KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-SEP-IT2ZTR26TO4XFPTO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode random probability 0.50000000000
KUBE-SEP-ZXMNUKOKXUTL2MK2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere           

Chain KUBE-SEP-IT2ZTR26TO4XFPTO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.0.2           anywhere            
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp to:10.244.0.2:53

Chain KUBE-SEP-ZXMNUKOKXUTL2MK2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  10.244.0.3           anywhere            
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp to:10.244.0.3:53
```

Hence, if you can re-simulate the issue, try checking nat table entries to see if everything is proper.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to say Manish, but let me know if you mean is better to use flannel, or did u do something in ur iptables? please let me know. thank u. I also use flannel for my CNI, but still cannot access the pods from the maser node, unless I flush the iptables rule. iptables -F